# Converting a "A B [C] D" formatted file to a CSV file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a file which has contents on every line following this format (A, B, C, and D represent text):

```
A B [C] D
```

E.g.:

```
cat Cat [noun] This animal likes to eat mice.
```

- The first separator is the first occurrence of a space (" ") on a line.
- The second separator is the first occurrence of a space followed by a square opening bracket (" [").
- The final separator is the first occurrence of a square closing bracket followed by a space ("] ").

I want to convert all of the content in this file to a CSV file, where `@` is used in place of commas:

```
A@B@C@D
```

- The original file contains many foreign characters in UTF-8.
- There are no spaces or brackets within the contents of A and B.
- C sometimes contains spaces, but no brackets inside the two given.
- D contains anything from spaces, square brackets, etc. and the contents should remain unchanged by the conversion.

How can I convert this file to that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform char substitution. I suggest you use **sed** with regular expression. This is a piece of code corresponding to your example:

```
sed -r 's/( |\[|\])+/@/g' file_to_modify.txt > file_for_output.txt
```

For substituting every column in a specific way, the following form is used:

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^]]+)] (.*$)/\1@\2@\3@\4/g' f1.txt > f2.txt
```

Comment: This is replacing every space and bracket with "@", when it should only be replacing the first space and the first " [" and " ]".

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a task for regular expressions. The literal brackets make this a bit ugly, but here's one that matches your example text.

```
^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^]]+)\] (.*)$
```

You'll have to check the regular expression api of whatever language you're writing your code in. For help in creating regexes, I recommend Expresso: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: +1 but I'd make the 2nd term be `([^ ]+)` since space is the following delimiter

Comment: Thanks glenn, I missed the rule about no spaces in B. Now it's fixed.

Comment: How do I use this to convert every line in a file?

Answer (score 1):

The string looks like a user-defined `csv` fomart.
Maybe you can try `csv` module in `python`:

```
$ python3
>>> import csv, io, re
>>> '@'.join(next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(re.sub('[\[\]]', '\034', 'A B [c c c] D')), delimiter=' ', quotechar='\034')))
'A@B@c c c@D'
```

Comment: When I put some symbols at D, it outputs unusual results. E.g. `A B [c c c] D[hello]` outputs `A@B@c c c@D\x1chello\x1c`.